# Tapped delay line + ADALINE = Adaptive filter?

Tags: adaptive-filters, neural-network

When studying neural networks from Neural Networks and Learning Machines, by Simon Haykin, the author highlights the close similarity between of adaptive filtering and neural networks.

From a scalar-valued signal, if we put a tapped delay input along with an ADALINE (Adaptive Linear Neuron), do we have an adaptive filter? From this point of view, both areas become closely related.

PS: A good reference is [MathWorks - Adaptive Neural Network Filters](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ug/adaptive-neural-network-filters.html#bss4gqu-3)

Answer (score 0):

I think adaptive filter, and a single layer perceptron with MSE error, will be equivalent.

Comment: The main problem imho is that, for adaptive filters, $\mathbf{x}[n] = (x[n], x[n-1], ...)$. It is not necessarily true for neural networks. That is where a tapped delay line comes in.

Comment: Moreover, if we are talking about linear adaptive filtering, a nonlinear activation function prevents they from being equal. That is where ADALINE comes in.

Comment: A single layer perceptron with MSE loss is exactly like adaptive filter as I wrote. You align the samples in batches to match the input.